# convert Integer to Long in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

It prints the relevant class as `java.lang.Long` or `java.lang.String` but it is not converting.
Please help to solve this issue.

Is there some other easy way to do this.?

set in Java file

```
resolver.setAttirbutes("Long",Long.class);
resolver.setAttirbutes("String",String.class);
```

convert in VM file

```
$Long.parseLong($String.valueOf(2))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how static methods work. Does `Long.class.parseLong` exist in Java? No. You're not putting a static reference to `Long`, you're putting the class object which deals with reflection and classloading. For security reasons, Velocity doesn't even allow you to call any of the methods of a `Class` object other than `getName`. You want to pass a reference to `Long` itself, not `Long.class`, but that, unfortunately, isn't possible.

But since static methods can be called on any instance of that class as well, all you need is to put a `Long` object in the context, like `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `Long.valueOf(0)`.

And not even that, since Velocity can only store objects, and not primitive values, any `long` is actually a `Long`, and any `int` is actually an `Integer`, so you can just do something like:

```
#set ($two = 2)
$two.class -> java.lang.Integer

#set ($twoLong = $two.longValue())
$twoLong.class -> java.lang.Long

#set ($threeLong = $twoLong.valueOf('3'))
```

Comment: It really helps me a lot